# The estimation error in Kalman filter

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, estimation, optimal-control, kalman-filter

I aim to understand whether the estimation error in a standard Kalman filter with "active noise" can be zero (at some time).

More precisely, a state-space model is given by
\begin{align}
x_{t+1}&= Fx_t + G w_t\\
y_t&= Hx_t + v_t
\end{align}
where $w_t,v_t$ are pairwise independent and are i.i.d. according to $w_t\sim N(0,W)$ and $v_t\sim N(0,V)$. Denote the estimation error covariance as:
$$\Sigma_{t|t-1} = \mathbf{cov}(x_t-\mathbb{E}[x_t|y^{t-1}]).$$

It is clear that $\Sigma_{t|t-1}$ is positive semidefinite.

1. If we assume $W,V\succ0$, can we show that $\Sigma_{t|t-1}$ is positive definite at all times? in other words, there will always be an estimation error. (I even think that $W\succ0$ is sufficient)
2. If the correlation $\mathbb{E}[w_tv_t^T]\neq0$, does it change the answer?

Answer (score 2):

In general, $w$ and $v$ are assumed to be uncorrelated, so that doesn't change the answer. The covariance of the Kalman filter (KF) can be written concisely as follows:

$$ \Sigma_{k}^{-1} = \bigr( F_k \Sigma_{k-1} F_k^T + W \bigr)^{-1} + H^T_k V^{-1} H_k $$

where this form is can be computed using the [Woodbury Matrix Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) with the most popular form of the KF equations. This form isn't necessary but is the most simple for answering your question.

So, if we assume that $W \succ 0$ and $V \succ 0$ are positive definite, then the covariance matrix as computed by the KF will also be positive definite. This is because of the following properties:

1. The inverse of a positive definite matrix is positive definite, so if $A$ is positive definite, then $A^{-1}$ is also positive definite.
2. If $A$ is $n \times n$ positive definite matrix, and $B$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with rank $m$, then $C = BAB^T$ is a positive definite matrix.
3. If $A$ is an $n \times n$ positive definite matrix and $B$ is an $n \times n$ positive semi-definite matrix, then $A + B$ is positive definite.

This means that both terms in the previous equation are positive definite; thus, the sum of the terms is also positive definite. Therefore, as long as $W$ and $V$ are positive definite, then the covariance matrix will also be positive definite.

Comment: thanks. I do not think that the answer is valid when there is correlation since the prediction term in your formula is not true anymore. Also, in the uncorrelated case, the sufficiency of $V\succ0$ is transparent, but what about $W\succ 0,V\succeq0$?

Comment: Right. The KF assumes the process and observation noise are uncorrelated, so if somehow, there is a correlation, then the KF is not valid. You only need either $W$ or $V$ to be positive definite while the other is positive semi-definite. Properties 1 and 2 hold for positive semi-definite matrices as well (i.e., you can replace the word positive definite with positive semi-definite in 1 and 2) except you don't need rank $m$ on the $B$ matrix.

Comment: KF is valid when there is correlation, the only thing that changes is the prediction update which is incorrect in your formula. For the sufficiency of $W\succ0$, how does your formula changes when $V$ is not invertible?

Comment: @Morad Can you please share a reference where $w$ and $v$ are correlated? The KF assumes those random variables are not correlated... but I’d be interested if you’ve seen something different in literature. If $V$ is not invertible, then you can’t use the form I provided, but you can instead use the standard form.

Comment: 1. How can we use the standard form to show that the covariance is PD 2. The standard textbook by Kailath et al. "Linear estimation" presents the general form.

Comment: You can use properties 1, 2, and 3 in a similar way.

Comment: The standard form has $GWG^T$ which may be psd only, can you pls elaborate?